# SUMMARIST: Automated Text Summarization

Tags: text-mining

There is a text summarization project called SUMMARIST. Apparently it is able to perform abstractive text summarization. I want to give it a try but unfortunately the demo links on the website do not work. Does anybody have any information regarding this? How can I test this tool?

http://www.isi.edu/natural-language/projects/SUMMARIST.html

Regards,
PasMod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It dates back to 1998, so most likely has been abandoned, or "acquired" by Microsoft as the creator currently works there and has done since publishing that research.

See https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/ists97.pdf
and http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/cyl for the author. Maybe you could try to contact him.

Comment: Also, his other publications are at publications at http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/cyl/publication.aspx